# error with cv2.destroyAllWindws() on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I'm programing in python and opencv on Ubuntu but the cv2.destoyAllWindows() doesn't seem to work,as in this example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
# Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

# Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

when i press 'q' the program end but the window remain on the screen how ever on windows i didn't face such thing
any help I will be thankful

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04 and it works fine, fix your formatting to match how you are running the code

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham how can i do that? besides I'm running the code using the IDLE

Comment: it works fine in idle for me also.

Comment: then what is the problem with mine